# How to group records by date and category based on last modified time?

Tags: sql, self-join

I need to calculate the current amount for each day and category (stage, in my example) based on the last modification time.

EDIT: The tricky part is that when the id is missing, it should use the amount AND stage that it had on the last date that it wasn't missing.

It's a bit confusing, but please, check the screenshot and example below for further info.

Records Table

[image]

Expected Result

[image]

How to read this table:

```
sensor XXX was modified on day 1 to Stage A and Amount 100
sensor XXX was not touched on day 2
sensor XXX was modified on day 2 to Stage B and Amount 150
```

If there was only this sensor (XXX) in the table, the aggregation would be as follows:

```
Day 1
Stage A: 100
Stage B: 0
Stage C: 0

Day 2 (there's no modified time this day)
Stage A: 100 (uses the amount of previous day)
Stage B: 0
Stage C: 0

Day 3
Stage A: 0
Stage B: 0
Stage C: 100
```

Find the MRE below (PostgreSQL).

Records Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Sensors_Modified_Time" (
    "Modified_Time" TIMESTAMP,
    "sensorId" TEXT,
    "Stage" TEXT,
    "Amount" INT
);
INSERT INTO "Sensors_Modified_Time" VALUES
    ('2020-01-01 00:00:00','XXX','A',100),
    ('2020-01-03 00:00:00','XXX','B',150),
    ('2020-01-02 00:00:00','YYY','B',120),
    ('2020-01-04 00:00:00','YYY','C',140),
    ('2020-01-01 00:00:00','ZZZ','B',140),
    ('2020-01-02 00:00:00','ZZZ','B',120),
    ('2020-01-03 00:00:00','ZZZ','B',110);
```

Expected Result

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "AggregateByDay" (
    "Date" TIMESTAMP,
    "Stage" TEXT,
    "Amount" INT
);
INSERT INTO "AggregateByDay" VALUES
    ('2020-01-01 00:00:00','A',100),
    ('2020-01-01 00:00:00','B',140),
    ('2020-01-01 00:00:00','C',0),
    ('2020-01-02 00:00:00','A',100),
    ('2020-01-02 00:00:00','B',240),
    ('2020-01-02 00:00:00','C',0),
    ('2020-01-03 00:00:00','A',0),
    ('2020-01-03 00:00:00','B',380),
    ('2020-01-03 00:00:00','C',0),
    ('2020-01-04 00:00:00','A',0),
    ('2020-01-04 00:00:00','B',260),
    ('2020-01-04 00:00:00','C',140);
```

PS: Even though I tried my best, I know the title and whole post are a bit confusing, so, please, feel free to help me make it more readable. Thank you!

Comment: The logic for your calculations just does not make sense.  Where does the 380 come from, for instance?

Comment: XXX modified on Day 3 Stage B 150

YYY modified on Day 2 Stage B 120

ZZZ modified on Day 3 Stage B 110

380
@GordonLinoff

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I've edited the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want all days combined with all stages -- and missing data to be zeros.

Use `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join` to bring in the values:

```
select t.modified_time, s.stage,
       coalesce(sum(smt.amount), 0) as amount
from (select distinct modified_time from Sensors_Modified_Time
     ) t cross join
     (select distinct stage from Sensors_Modified_Time
     ) s left join
     Sensors_Modified_Time smt
     on smt.modified_time = t.modified_time and
        smt.stage = s.stage
group by t.modified_time, s.stage
order by t.modified_time, s.stage;
```

This doesn't return exactly the values specified in the question, but I think this is what you really want to do.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=efd0c0ff83734245f106f4b3158efc45) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

Ahhh, now I get it.  For each sensor you want to remember the most recent value for each stage.  Then you want to add that up at a given time for the stage.  One method for doing this is a lateral join -- in combination with the `cross join`:

```
select t.modified_time, s.stage,
       coalesce(smt.amount, 0) as amount
from (select distinct modified_time from Sensors_Modified_Time
     ) t cross join
     (select distinct stage from Sensors_Modified_Time
     ) s left join lateral
     (select sum(amount) as amount
      from (select distinct on (smt.sensorid) smt.*
            from Sensors_Modified_Time smt
            where smt.modified_time <= t.modified_time and
                  smt.stage = s.stage
            order by smt.sensorid, smt.modified_time desc
           ) smt
     ) smt
     on 1=1
order by t.modified_time, s.stage;
```

I modified the db<>fiddle to have this as well.

Comment: Almost that! I want missing data to have the same Amount as it had in the last time it wasn't missing.

In the example I gave, XXX should have 100 as Stage A in Day 2 (day it was missing) because that's what it had in Day 1 (the last time it wasn't missing)

Comment: Sorry, English is not my first language and I should have put more thought when writing it down.

Thanks for working through it, I'll test it tomorrow with the real data and accept your answer as a solution as soon as I confirm that everything's fine.

Comment: "For each sensor you want to remember the most recent value for each stage."

I want to remember only the most recent value AND its stage. Not in a cumulative way. Example below.

Day 4
- XXX has record this day? No.
- Most recent Stage & Amount for this id? Stage B and Amount 150 on Day 3.
- Add 150 to Stage B to Day 4

- YYY has record this day? Yes.
- Add 140 to Stage C to Day 4

- ZZZ has record this day? No.
- Most recent Stage & Amount for this id? Stage B and Amount 110 on Day 3.
- Add 110 to Stage B to Day 4

Day 4 Total
A 0
B 260
C 140

Does that make sense?